# Why isn't the "and" operator working properly in my game?

Tags: python, if-statement

This program is for a tic tac toe game and I designed a function to check for when either X or O would win. The `if` statement is practically the same just for different lines but every time I put in a certain position in the board it will print "X wins" despite not having all three X's, which makes me think the `and` operator isn't working.

Does anybody have any input as to what could be happening?

```
if ("X" in (board[0][0] and board[2][0] and board[4][0])) or ("X" in (board[0][0] and board[0][2] and board[0][4])):
    print("X wins")

board = [[" ", "|" ," ", "|" ," "],
         ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
         [" ", "|" ," ", "|" ," "],
         ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"],
         [" ", "|" ," ", "|" ," "],
         ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]]
```

Comment: Python's `and` is a boolean operator, not an English conjunction; it doesn't work like that.

Comment: `and` is a *operator* used in boolean expressions, not a statement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in your parentheses. Specifically:

```
(board[0][0] and board[2][0] and board[4][0])
```

will evaluate to a string in your case. And this program will test if "X" in (string).
I think what you want to test is if "X" is in all 3 of these spaces. You could do it like this:

```
if ("X" in board[0][0] and "X" in board[2][0] and "X" in board[4][0])
```

Just one example of what you could do, but this should help you out!